# matching against already assigned variable in case of expression

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

The following code in Erlang catches the value of 3 if its equivalent to the value that Four is assigned to:

```
run() ->
    Four = 4,
    case 3 of
        Four -> io:format("3 == 4~n", []);
        _ -> io:format("3 /= 4~n", [])
    end.
```

When executed it prints out "3 /= 4". Similar code in Haskell:

```
main = do
    let four = 4
    case 3 of
        four -> putStrLn "3 == 4"
        _ -> putStrLn "3 /= 4"
```

prints "3 == 4" which is a statement I'm not (at this point in my life) ready to accept as truth.

Why does Haskell not let me match against previously bound variables? Is it per design or just a result of how do-notation (and case .. of expressions by the way, I tested binding a name to a value in one case .. of and then matching against it in another case .. of inside and it didn't work) are implemented?
Is there some way to get it to work and be as cool and simple as the Erlang one or do I have to manually compare them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This comes from the general static scoping rules, and renaming of variables (alpha-conversion). E.g. we know that

```
(\x -> x + 1)
```

is the same as

```
(\y -> y + 1)
```

in any context. This works in the same way for other binders:

```
let x = 1 in f x  -- is the same as
let y = 1 in f y
```

Also

```
case e of x -> f x -- is the same as
case e of y -> f y
```

Some languages, such as Erlang, decided to break this general renaming rule, special-casing pattern matching against a variable defined in an outer scope.
I'd say most functional languages decided instead to follow it.

In Haskell you can achieve the same using

```
case e of v | v == previousVariable -> ...
```

Note that this requires `(==)`, so an `Eq` instance must be available. That is, it works for `Int`s, but not for functions (or other types lacking a comparator).

Comment: is there no Haskell equivalent of Scala's `3 match { case \`four\` => ... }`?

Comment: @ErikAllik AFAIK, no, you need to use the guarded pattern `v | v == four -> ...`.

Answer (score 0):

In this case Haskell does not compare the value of `four = 4` to `3` it uses `four` as a **pattern** (which in this case will catch everything) so to the right of `->` `four` will now be `four == 3` (it shadows the binding above)

you probably want

```
let four = 4
case 3 of
    x | four == x -> putStrLn "3 == 4"
      | otherwise -> putStrLn "3 /= 4"
```

inestead